# Mathias forcing with Ramsey ultrafilters, and Cohen reals

Tags: forcing, lo.logic, set-theory, ultrafilters

Edit/update: One reason this question never received an answer is because it was founded on a faulty premise! The Blaszczyk-Shelah paper I mentioned below does not prove that Mathias forcing with a nowhere-dense ultrafilter does not add Cohen reals. That statement is false. (I am not quite sure where I got the misconception). They do construct a sigma-centered forcing which doesn't add Cohen reals using a nowhere dense ultrafilter and topological methods, but the forcing is something else.

In fact, one can show that Mathias forcing $\mathbb{M} _ {\mathcal{U}}$ relative to an ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ adds Cohen reals exactly when $\mathcal{U}$ is not selective. For selective ultrafilters $\mathbb{M} _ {\mathcal{U}}$ has the Laver property, which implies it doesn't add Cohen reals. And if $\mathcal{U}$ isn't selective, that means one can partition $\omega=\bigcup_{k<\omega}A_k$ where each $A_k\not\in\mathcal{U}$, and so that no $A\in\mathcal{U}$ has the cardinality of its intersections with the $A_k$ bounded by some $M<\omega$ independent of $k$. Let $g$ be the generic real. Let $x\in V[g]\cap\omega^\omega$ be the real defined by having $x(n)=k$ where $g(n)\in A_k$. Then, let $y(i)$ equal the number of times the $i$th distinct digit of $x$ repeats. It is not hard to see that $y\in V[g]\cap\omega^\omega$ is a Cohen real.

I'll leave the question as I wrote it below, since I'm not bashful about being mistaken. Although it is probably appropriate to close this as 'not a real question'.

---

Given an ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ on $\omega$ the corresponding Mathias forcing $\mathbb{M}_\mathcal{U}$ is the forcing consisting of conditions $\langle s,A\rangle$ where $s$ is a finite subset of $\omega$ and $A\in\mathcal{U}$. The ordering is given by $\langle t,B\rangle\leq\langle s,A\rangle$ if $B\subseteq A$ and $t$ is an end extension of $s$, with $t\setminus s\subseteq A$. (So $\mathbb{M} _\mathcal{U}$ is just like Prikry forcing, but the relevant objects are defined on $\omega$.)

An ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ is nowhere dense if whenever $F:\omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ there is some $A\in\mathcal{U}$ whose image under $A$ is nowhere dense. Blaszczyk and Shelah have shown that when $\mathcal{U}$ is nowhere dense, then $\mathbb{M} _\mathcal{U}$ does not add a Cohen real. In fact, they proved that the existence of a $\sigma$-centered forcing adding no Cohen real is equivalent to the existence of a nowhere dense ultrafilter.

Their proof that $\mathbb{M} _\mathcal{U}$ adds no Cohen real mostly uses topological methods rather than forcing theoretic ones, and I find it a bit opaque. I was wondering if a simpler proof was known if we add some stronger hypotheses on the ultrafilter. My question is:

Is there a (relatively) simple proof that when $\mathcal{U}$ is a Ramsey ultrafilter $\mathbb{M}_\mathcal{U}$ adds no Cohen real? What about for p-points?

Comment: vanilla Mathias forcing (without an ultrafilter) doesn't add Cohen reals, but Mathias forcing with an ultrafilter very well might; in Shelah's model with no nowhere dense ultrafilter every Mathias forcing with an ultrafilter and indeed every sigma-centered forcing will add a Cohen real

Comment: i didn't think about the Laver property, that's a very good suggestion

Comment: Ramiro, your suggestion seems to be right; I think the same diagonal arguments that show vanilla Mathias forcing has the Laver property shows that Mathias forcing relative to a Ramsey ultrafilter does.. if you wanted to add your suggestion as an answer I would certainly upvote it...

Comment: in the meantime I've 'strengthened' the question by also asking about p-points, where it isn't clear that the forcing has the Laver property (and I would guess, perhaps, it does not)

Comment: (Closed per author's request.)

Comment: In the second paragraph of the edit, the sentence "And if $\mathcal U$ isn't selective, that means ..." seems to describe non-P-points rather than non-selective ultrafilters.  In the case of a non-selective P-point, there would be an $A$ that meets each $A_k$ in only finitely many points (but the "finitely many" would not be bounded independently of $k$).  

Comment: Ah right, yes I was mentally conflating bounded and finite. (The Cohen real I described only needs the $A$ in $\mathcal{U}$ to have unbounded intersection with the $A_k$). Thanks

Comment: Even though this wasn't a real question, I still found it extremely useful (I was trying to prove that certain ultraLaver forcing doesn't add Cohen reals, even though the ultrafilter in question is not a P-point. Thanks to this post, now I know that this is, most likely, impossible).

Comment: A possibly simpler way of getting the Cohen real:  Let $g\in \omega^\omega$ be the generic real, a strictly increasing sequence.  Let  $c(i)=0$ if $g(i)$ and $g(i+1)$ are in the same class of the partition $(A_k:k\in \omega)$, and $c(i)=1$ otherwise.  Then $c\in 2^\omega$ is a Cohen real. (The proof uses the fact that the intersections of $ran(g)$ with the $A_k$ are not bounded.)