# Interesting examples of countable support iteration of ccc forcings

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, lo.logic, forcing

I am looking for examples in the literature of *countable support* iterations of ccc (particularly $\sigma$-centered) forcings, possibly with some emphasis on iterations that avoid adding Cohen reals.

Alternatively, I would also be interested in reasons why such iterations are "uninteresting", for reasons other than the usual limitations on cs iteration.

Comment: Don't $\sigma$-centered po-sets always add a Cohen? Or is that an open question? I vaugely remember something about the existence of a certain type of ultrafilter being required.

Comment: @NotMike If $\mathcal{U}$ is a selective ultrafilter, then the restricted Mathias (or Laver) forcing with side conditions in $\mathcal{U}$ is $\sigma$-centered, but does not add Cohen reals. See, e.g.: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96930/mathias-forcing-with-ramsey-ultrafilters-and-cohen-reals. These are the sorts of forcings I'm thinking about.

Comment: I wouldn't call such iterations "uninteresting". Miyamoto's thesis may have results along these lines. In particular, I think he showed the countable support iteration of Cohen forcing of weakly compact length forces $\omega_2$ has the tree property.

Comment: @IianSmythe Thank you for clearing up my confusion.